Longer boot time with bluetooth keyboard?
I've recently switched to using a bluetooth keyboard. Now every time my workstation boots up, I get a warning message "No keyboard detected".
I felt this lengthened the boot time, so I timed a few. It adds roughly 9 seconds to the reboot time (~35 seconds versus ~26 seconds). Can I avoid this?
I am using ASUS UEFI BIOS Utility version 1402 x64 09/08/2023. I see no option to address it in the BIOS settings. I know elsewhere some have suggested connecting a spare wired keyboard, but I don't have one. Perhaps there is another solution, or knowledge of a fix in an updated release of the ASUS BIOS?

There is no solution.
